# Generate pdf with jsPDF, cannot deselect AcroformRadioButton in Chrome

Tags: javascript, node.js, jspdf

I'm using jsPDF to generate pdf documents in nodejs. I created RadioButton following the Acroforms example provided here (http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/index.html#). I was able to toggle off the radio butotns when open it in some browser like Chrome, Safari. But it didn't work when open in Acrobat. Any idea why? How can I make toggling radio button off works in pdf readers like Acrobat?

Followed example code provided by jsPDF. Expect to be able to toggle off radio button, but it didn't work when opened in Acrobat.

```
  var { RadioButton, Appearance } = jsPDF.AcroForm;

  doc.text("RadioGroup:", 50, 165);
  var radioGroup = new RadioButton();
  radioGroup.value = "Test";
  radioGroup.Subtype = "Form";

  doc.addField(radioGroup);

  var radioButton1 = radioGroup.createOption("Test");
  radioButton1.Rect = [50, 170, 30, 10];
  radioButton1.AS = "/Test";

  var radioButton2 = radioGroup.createOption("Test2");
  radioButton2.Rect = [50, 180, 30, 10];

  var radioButton3 = radioGroup.createOption("Test3");
  radioButton3.Rect = [50, 190, 20, 10];

  radioGroup.setAppearance(Appearance.RadioButton.Cross);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

As described we can use the online sampler for a Live "fiddle"

[image]

Where the action is clear pick ANY one from 3 boxes (Just like a "Radio Group") The design of a Radio Group is such that, **any one but no other**, box can be chosen. and on picking one the file needs to on closure be saved with LAST choice.

In your Question code you have a surplus `};` at the end that will block the demo output.

This works perfectly as per design in Acrobat Reader. OR Ms Edge or most PDF viewers, including Chrome.
[image]
[image]
[image]

**Here we see the choice is any one of 3 options from the Group `FieldObject0`**

[image]

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
var {
  CheckBox,
  RadioButton,
  Appearance
} = jsPDF.AcroForm;

doc.setFontSize(20);
doc.text("CheckBox:", 10, 25);

var checkBox = new CheckBox();
checkBox.fieldName = "CheckBox1";
checkBox.Rect = [60, 17, 10, 10];
doc.addField(checkBox);
doc.text("Acrobat:", 70, 25);
var checkBox = new CheckBox();
checkBox.fieldName = "CheckBox2";
checkBox.Rect = [60, 27, 10, 10];
doc.addField(checkBox);
doc.text("Chrome:", 70, 35);
doc.text("RadioGroup:", 10, 45);
var radioGroup = new RadioButton();
radioGroup.value = "Test";
radioGroup.Subtype = "Form";
doc.addField(radioGroup);

var radioButton1 = radioGroup.createOption("Yes");
radioButton1.Rect = [60, 38, 10, 10];
doc.text("Yes:", 75, 45);
radioButton1.AS = "/Test";
doc.text("Works:", 10, 55);
var radioButton2 = radioGroup.createOption("Undecided");
radioButton2.Rect = [60, 48, 10, 10];
doc.text("Maybe:", 75, 55);

var radioButton3 = radioGroup.createOption("No");
radioButton3.Rect = [60, 58, 10, 10];
doc.text("No:", 75, 65);
radioGroup.setAppearance(Appearance.RadioButton.Circle);
```